# What would be the best magic robes for me to use?

Tags: runescape

What would be the best robes for me on Runescape? My magic level 60, and my defense is 61. I am looking for high hp and defense bonus, and non degradable and cheap (I have 1M to spend on it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two armours I would recommend:

**Enchanted Robes:**

- Magic Level: 40
- Defence Level: 45
- Constitution Level: 10
- HP Bonus: 2430
- Defence Bonus: 475
- Degradable: No
- Cost: 150k in GE

**Batwing Robes:**

- Magic Level: 50
- Defence Level: 50
- Constitution Level: 10
- Defence Bonus: 666
- HP Bonus: 3755
- Degradable: No
- Cost: 25k in GE

Those are my recommendations for your combat stats. Of course there is more at:[Runescape Wiki - Magic Armour](https://runescape.wiki/w/Armour/Magic_armour)

These armours should be used because they are cheap, and like you stated before, you are looking for a decent defence bonus. These are by far the cheapest robes for your level that also provide the best non degradable defence bonuses (besides infinity robes).

For more information, please see the link provided.

Comment: Why should these armors be used?  Give your reasoning, please.

Comment: I added my reasoning.